# What is the encoding scheme for this Arabic web page?

Tags: html, encoding, arabic

I am trying to find the encoding scheme for this page (and others) which are surely **Arabic**, using lower ASCII range Latin characters to encode the contents.

http://www.saintcyrille.com/2011a.htm

http://www.saintcyrille.com/2011b.htm (English version/translation of that same page)

I have seen several sites and even PDF documents with this encoding, but I can't find the name or method of it.

This specific page is from 2011 and I think this is a pre-Unicode method of encoding Arabic that has fallen out of fashion.

Some sample text:

```
'D1J'6) 'D1H-J) 'DA5-J)
*#ED'* AJ 3A1 'D*CHJF
JDBJG'
'D#( / 3'EJ -D'B 'DJ3H9J 
'D0J J#*J .5J5'K EF -D( @ 3H1J'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extraordinary [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. It looks like there is missing high byte in Unicode code points in Arabic text. For instance: `ا` (U+0627, *Arabic Letter Alef*) appears as `'` (U+0027, *Apostrophe*).

Let's suppose that missing high byte is always `0x06` in the following PowerShell script (added some more strings from the very end of the page http://www.saintcyrille.com/2011a.htm to your sample text):

```
$mojibakes = @'
E3'!K
'D1J'6) 'D1H-J) 'DA5-J)
*#ED'* AJ 3A1 'D*CHJF
JDBJG'
'D#( / 3'EJ -D'B 'DJ3H9J 
'D0J J#*J .5J5'K EF -D( @ 3H1J'
ED'-8'* :
'D#CD 'D5J'EJ 7H'D 'D#3(H9 'D98JE E-(0 ,/'K H'D5HE JF*GJ (9/ B/'3 'D9J/
J-(0 'D*B/E DD'9*1'A (9J/'K 9F JHE 'D9J/ (B/1 'D%EC'F -*I *3*7J9H' 'DE4'1C) AJ 'D5DH'* HB/'3 'D9J/  HFF5- D0DC  'D'3*A'/) EF -AD) 'D*H() 'D,E'9J) JHE 'D,E9) 15 '(1JD 2011 -J+ JGJ# 'D,EJ9 E9'K DFH'D 31 'DE5'D-) ( 9// EF 'D#('! 'DCGF) 3JCHF -'61'K )
(5F/HB 'D5HE) 9F/ E/.D 'DCFJ3) AAJ A*1) 'D#9J'/ *8G1 AJF' #9E'D 'D1-E) H'D5/B'* HE' JB'(DG' H0DC 9ED EB(HD HEE/H-
HDF' H7J/ 'D#ED #F *4'1CH' 'D'-*A'D'* AJ 19J*CE HCD 9'E H#F*E (.J1
'DE3J- B@'E ... -@B'K B@'E
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

Function highByte ([byte]$lowByte, [switch]$moreInfo) {
    if ( $moreInfo.IsPresent -and (
            $lowByte -lt 0x20 -or $lowByte -gt 0x7f )) {
        Write-Host $lowByte -ForegroundColor Cyan 
    }
    if ( $lowByte -eq 0x20 ) { 0,$lowByte } else { 6,$lowByte }
}

foreach ( $mojibake in $mojibakes ) {
    $aux = [System.Text.Encoding]::
        GetEncoding( 1252).GetBytes( [char[]]$mojibake )
    [System.Text.Encoding]::BigEndianUnicode.GetString(
        $aux.ForEach({(highByte -lowByte $_)})
    )
    '' # new line separator for better readability
}
```

Output (using [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ar&tl=en&text=1%0A%D9%85%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%A1%D9%8B%0A%0A%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B6%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B5%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%A9%0A%0A%D8%AA%D8%A3%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%B3%D9%81%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%83%D9%88%D9%8A%D9%86%0A%0A%D9%8A%D9%84%D9%82%D9%8A%D9%87%D8%A7%0A%0A%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%A8%20%D8%AF%20%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%8A%20%D8%AD%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%82%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B9%D9%8A%0A%0A%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B0%D9%8A%20%D9%8A%D8%A3%D8%AA%D9%8A%20%D8%AE%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%8B%20%D9%85%D9%86%20%D8%AD%D9%84%D8%A8%20%D9%80%20%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7%0A%0A%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%B8%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D8%BA%0A%0A%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%83%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%8A%20%D8%B7%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B8%D9%8A%D9%85%20%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%B0%20%D8%AC%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%8B%20%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%85%20%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%AA%D9%87%D9%8A%20%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%AF%20%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B3%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%AF%0A%0A%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%B0%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%82%D8%AF%D9%85%20%D9%84%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%81%20%D8%A8%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%8B%20%D8%B9%D9%86%20%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%AF%20%D8%A8%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D9%85%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D8%AD%D8%AA%D9%89%20%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%B7%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%A7%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%A9%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D9%88%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B3%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%AF%20%D8%8C%20%D9%88%D9%86%D9%86%D8%B5%D8%AD%20%D9%84%D8%B0%D9%84%D9%83%20%D8%8C%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9%20%D9%85%D9%86%20%D8%AD%D9%81%D9%84%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A9%20%D8%B1%D8%B5%20%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%84%20%D8%B2%D8%B0%D8%B1%D8%B1%20%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%AB%20%D9%8A%D9%87%D9%8A%D8%A3%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B9%20%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%8B%20%D9%84%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%20%D8%B3%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%A9%20%D8%A8%20%D8%B9%D8%AF%D8%AF%20%D9%85%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D9%87%D9%86%D8%A9%20%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%83%D9%88%D9%86%20%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%8B%20%D8%A9%0A%0A%D8%A8%D8%B5%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%82%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A9%20%D8%B9%D9%86%D8%AF%20%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%AE%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%B3%D8%A9%20%D9%81%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF%20%D8%AA%D8%B8%D9%87%D8%B1%20%D9%81%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D8%A3%D8%B9%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%A9%20%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%AF%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A7%20%D9%8A%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%84%D9%87%D8%A7%20%D9%88%D8%B0%D9%84%D9%83%20%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%84%20%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%84%20%D9%88%D9%85%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%AD%0A%0A%D9%88%D9%84%D9%86%D8%A7%20%D9%88%D8%B7%D9%8A%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%85%D9%84%20%D8%A3%D9%86%20%D8%AA%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%83%D9%88%D8%A7%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%B1%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%AA%D9%83%D9%85%20%D9%88%D9%83%D9%84%20%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D9%88%D8%A3%D9%86%D8%AA%D9%85%20%D8%A8%D8%AE%D9%8A%D8%B1%0A%0A%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%AD%20%D9%82%D9%80%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D8%AE%D8%AE%D8%AE%20%D8%AD%D9%80%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%8B%20%D9%82%D9%80%D8%A7%D9%85&op=translate)) seems to give a sense roughly similar to [English version of the page](http://www.saintcyrille.com/2011b.htm), after a fashion…

**Output**: `.\SO\70062779.ps1`

> مساءً
>
> الرياضة الروحية الفصحية
>
> تأملات في سفر التكوين
>
> يلقيها
>
> الأب د سامي حلاق اليسوعي
>
> الذي يأتي خصيصاً من حلب ـ سوريا
>
> ملاحظات غ
>
> الأكل الصيامي طوال الأسبوع العظيم محبذ جداً والصوم ينتهي بعد قداس
> العيد
>
> يحبذ التقدم للاعتراف بعيداً عن يوم العيد بقدر الإمكان حتى تستطيعوا
> المشاركة في الصلوات وقداس العيد ، وننصح لذلك ، الاستفادة من حفلة
> التوبة الجماعية يوم الجمعة رص ابريل زذرر حيث يهيأ الجميع معاً لنوال سر
> المصالحة ب عدد من الأباء الكهنة سيكون حاضراً ة
>
> بصندوق الصومة عند مدخل الكنيسة ففي فترة الأعياد تظهر فينا أعمال الرحمة
> والصدقات وما يقابلها وذلك عمل مقبول وممدوح
>
> ولنا وطيد الأمل أن تشاركوا الاحتفالات في رعيتكم وكل عام وأنتم بخير
>
> المسيح قـام خخخ حـقاً قـام

**Please keep in mind** that I do not understand Arabic.

- The script does not handle numbers: year `2011` in note #2 is incorrectly transformed to `زذرر`, for instance;
- Handling spaces is unclear: is `0x20` always a space, or should be transformed to `ؠ` (U+0620, *Arabic Letter Kashmiri Yeh*)?
- moreover, there is that problematic presumption about Unicode range U+0600-U+067F (where are U+0680-U+06FF and others?).

Comment: Thank you so much! a simple, elegant solution to my question!